# C# retrieve the set of rows for a given key

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

i have a data table

```
ID        Name      Parent_ID      New_Value
A_304     X123       NULL             x233
B_304     X333       A_304            DW
C_304     x323       A_304            455
D_404     C3333      NULL             233
E_304     X333       D_404            444
F_304     x323       D_404            455
```

now i am able to parse this data table and a make a xml file like this by iterating each of the row

```
<Components>
  <component id = "A_304"  Name="X123"       Parent_ID="NULL"      New_Value="x233">
      <subcomponent id = "B_304"  Name="X333"       Parent_ID="A_304"      New_Value="DW" />
      <subcomponent id = "C_304"  Name="x323"       Parent_ID="A_304"      New_Value="455" />
   </component>
    <component id = "A_304"  Name="D_404"       Parent_ID="NULL"      New_Value="x233">
      <subcomponent id = "E_304"  Name="X333"       Parent_ID="D_404"      New_Value="44" />
      <subcomponent id = "F_304"  Name="x323"       Parent_ID="D_404"      New_Value="455" />
   </component>   
</Components>
```

Can any one provide me pointers to how to achieve this using LINQ query?

Thanks for the help.

EDIT : Code to parse the data table

```
 #region FramingOutput
            for (int i = 0; i < dataset1.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //once we Read whole Row from the table. We need to check weather it is a parent or child.
                // parent component will not have parent id populated.
                //we need to check for every component weather it has the parent id same as previous component ID

                #region FirstRow
                //Assuming the first Row is always a Parent so Creating a parent Tag.
                if ( i == 0)
                {
                   ParentComponent = CreateParent(dataset1, i, out ParentID);  //method to create a parent tag
                   continue;
                }
                #endregion

                ischild = checkischild(dataset1, i);
                if(ischild == true)
                {
                   ChildComponent =  CreateChild(dataset1, i);  //method to create a child tag
                   ParentComponent.Add(ChildComponent);
                }
                else
                {
                    Components.Add(ParentComponent);
                    ParentComponent = CreateParent(dataset1, i, out ParentID);
                }


            }
```

Comment: Add code which you are currently using to parse the data table and make the above xml file.

Comment: Youve showed *some* of the code used to parse it, but not the important parts `CreateChild` and `checkischild`

Comment: So, the list is self referential, can it go multiple layers deep or just 1. i.e. are there grandparents and great-grandparents etc?

Comment: *to achieve this* to achieve **what** ? I mean, what exactly do you want to do *using LINQ query* ?

Comment: People suggested me to go through  LINQ so that it would be fast for large number of rows. i am new to C#. So any good web references will be appreciated

Comment: tell me if that isn't a duplicate.

Comment: `People suggested me to go through LINQ so that it would be fast for large number of rows` if anything, LINQ will be *slower* for a large number of rows. It certainly doesnt do any magic, it just simplifies wring lots of loops.